# Openssl algorithm for big endian microcontroller

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, openssl, endianness

As part of my project, I need to communicate between Electronic unit A(big endian) and B (little endian). The communication between the two electronic units should be encrypted (16 byte encryption)using OpenSSL algorithm.

I have a doubt about this approach.
Is the OpenSSL algorithm little endian specific ?
if OpenSSL algorithm is created as library and the that library to be used in A code and B code to perform encryption/decryption, how to make sure the endian difference between A and B does not effect the accuracy of the algorithm.

I tried to explain the problem as simple as possible. Please add comment if additional information required.

Comment: OpenSSL is not an algorithm.  It is a library.  It is cross-platform, including big- and little- endian architectures.  However, it is still not an algorithm.

Comment: I agree with @DietrichEpp you want SSL protocol. The OpenSSL is library not algorithm. Librraries like this usually use platform defined `#define token` to konfigure itself. If your **MCU** compiler is not recognized correctly you can see inside the sources of OpenSSL and look for statements like `#ifdef blablabla`  and from the names deduce what to define prior to `#include <OpenSSL.h>` or whatever to force the endianness.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Dietrich Epp